# Work around for Alexa Custom Skill Reoccuring response

Tags: java, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a custom `Alexa` skill
In which I can ask the name of User and repeat it. (Working fine).
Now, the next part is to confirm the name of the user.

```
Alexa: "Please confirm your name!"<br>
User:"-"

Alexa: "Please confirm your name!"<br>
User: "No"

Alexa: "Please confirm your name!"<br>
**User: "Yes I confirm"**  
End.
```

Now I am trying to achieve the above behaviour, as 
Alexa should prompt `"Please confirm your name!"` on every 10 seconds until the user Responds

```
"Yes, I confirm".
```

I have checked the API documentation but not able to find any Intent related to this case.

Please share some info or solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not possible to make Alexa ask the question every 10 seconds untill the user confirm.

I suppose you are using **confirmSlotDirective** to confirm the name of the user.

**confirmSlotDirective** or simply any confirmation directive in Alexa works with words that only **agree** or **disagree** with the confirmation message. e.g. **YES/NO**

Solution:

**1**) If you have already asked for the name of the user (e.g. 'John'), do not ask it again. Simply make Alexa to say:

**Alexa**: "Your name is John, right?" Or "You said John? please confirm?"

**User**: can say Yes/No to confirm.

**Note**: Alexa only recognizes a limited set of international names.

**2**) Better way to get user's name is using Alexa's [Customer Profile Api](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/ffcafcdd-75c8-4136-b8a5-bb09155e2088/request-permission-and-access-contact-information-with-the-new-customer-profile-api), so you won't have to worry about Alexa not able to recognize name let alone the confirmation of user's name.

Comment: Thanks for  the response. I'll try this way

Answer (score 1):

Repromting every 10 seconds when the user doesn't responds, not sure if we can do.

But we can achieve the Yes/No part. One way of doing this is by using the state. Here in this example, I am using the [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) module for state management.

Consider the below intent named "ConfirmationQuestionIntent". It sets the state to "confirm-name".

```
const ConfirmationQuestionIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "ConfirmationQuestionIntent"
    );
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = "Please confirm your name as 'John'.";
    myCache.set('state','confirm-name');
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Now, enable/Add two BuiltIn intents, AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent. 
Consider the AMAZON.NoIntent below,
In the handler function. it checks if there is any state with the name "confirm-name". If it is present, it responds with "Please confirm your name as 'John'." and if not then responds with the default response.

```
const NoBuiltInIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "AMAZON.NoIntent"
    );
  },

  handle(handlerInput) {
    const state = myCache.get("state");
    let speechText = "I didn't get this!. Could you please rephrase.";
    if(state === "confirm-name") speechText = "Please confirm your name as 'John'.";
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Consider the AMAZON.YesIntent below,
In the handle function, it checks if there is any state named "confirm-name". If it is, then it responds back with "Thanks for the confirmation" and deletes the state from the cache. If not then it asks the user to rephrase.

```
const YesBuiltInIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "AMAZON.YesIntent"
    );
  },

  handle(handlerInput) {
    const state = myCache.get("state");
    let speechText = "I didn't get this!. Could you please rephrase.";
    if(state === "confirm-name") speechText = "Thanks for the confirmation.";
    myCache.del('state');
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

So, you can use "State" to identify in which scenario the user is responding to and then provide the right response.

Comment: @shardha, Thanks let me apply this 
Also , can you share a snippet of Java if possible?

Comment: @mohitsharma Sorry, I don't know much about JAVA :)

Comment: Alright, Just one more case I have 
Do alexa  skill support DropIn programmatically.
Alexa 1 send message to  Alexa 2 on another location>>